# How to append ul and where div id is the same as append ul class with jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

How to append ul and where div id is the same as append ul class with jquery? but i try but i'm not success please send me reason

```
<div class="mainrow">
<div class="row">
<div class="cated1" id="cate1">cate1</div>
<div class="cated1" id="cate2">cate2</div>
</div>
<div class="appendrow">
<ul class="cate1">
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>
</ul>  
<ul class="cate2">
<li>test2</li>
<li>test2</li>
</ul>    
</div>    
</div> 

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
var idrow = $(".mainrow .cated1").attr("id");
$("ul").each(function(index, element) {
alert($(this).appendTo(idrow));
});

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `attr()` in this way:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("ul").each(function (index, element) {
        // $(this) will give current ul reference and .attr("class") will give its class name
        alert($(this).appendTo($("div#" + $(this).attr("class"))));
    });

});
```

### FIDDLE DEMO:

http://jsfiddle.net/ehsansajjad465/f3gzks0p/

Answer (score 0):

Please check following code. I hope you get the reasons :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var idrow = $(".mainrow .cated1").attr("id");
    $("ul").each(function(index, element) {
    alert($(this).appendTo($('#'+idrow)));
    });
});
```

You just get the ID value using attr(). But when you need appendTo() you need object(s) as parameter not string.